# [Postfix]Some recipients in a mail group rejected when delivery?

Tags: postfix

There are 2 Postfix mail servers msA and msB, responsible for domainA and domainB repectively. Setting of Postfix on both server is:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_sender_login_mismatch,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unlisted_sender
```

There is a special user used as mail group: somegroup@domainA, defined in LDAP, which includes user1 and user2@domainB in a property of somegroup.

When I sent mail through server B with sender: user2@domainB and recipient: somegroup@domainA, user1 got the mail, but user2 didn't. User2 got a mail said that msA responded with "user not login" error, then.

If I changed the setting of Postfix on serverA to:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_unlisted_sender
```

and resend the mail, then neither user1 and user2 get the mail.

All users and mailgroups are defined on the LDAP server.

What setting should I set to make both user got the mail?